# Import Excel data and update table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to both import Excel data and update an existing table with the imported data in one go? Right now I import the data in a new table and merge the tables. Just curious if there is a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a sensible approach: load the raw data into a staging table gives you the chance to do (a) validation, (b) adaption of data (where needed) and so forth. I would leave it as is.

Comment: How do you merge data? Via `MERGE` statement?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, is just an idea.

```
WITH MyExcelQuery AS (
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET( /* Map your xls here */)
)
MERGE MyTable
USING MyExcelQuery
ON /* continue with the merge statement */
```